# Trying to get a value from POST method

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I'm trying to save a string in a variable, send the value using POST and then get it using GET.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/memory_usage", (_req, res) => res.send(process.memoryUsage()));

app.use("/", (_req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.meow = "Meow";
  next();
});

app.post("/message/:string", (_req, res) => res.send(res.locals.meow));

app.get("/message", (_req, res) => res.send);

app.listen(3333);
```

I'm new to Express.js and I've tried to 'get' the value through a middleware so I could return it in GET in the past and that worked pretty well. But I'm trying to achieve the same using POST.

Comment: `res.locals` exists ONLY for the duration of this specific request.  You can't save something there in one request and then access it in another request.  To do that, you would probably use a user session object (`express-session` module) that creates an object for each user and allows you to save some state form one request to the next.  Though, in general an http server scales best with as little per-user state as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.locals` exists ONLY for the duration of this specific request.  You can't save something there in one request and then access it in another request.

To do that, you would probably use a user session object (`express-session` module) that creates an object for each user and allows you to save some state form one request to the next.  Though, in general an http server scales best with as little per-user state as possible so it's better if state is kept in the client and then presented to the server as needed (cookies is one way of doing that).